# WIF: renew session at STS

Tags: asp.net, wif

I use an external IDP (STS) and have a WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) enabled ASP.NET application. The IDP has a session timeout of 30min. In my application there is 20min sliding exp. timeout. This causes problem when the STS gets timeout and kill the session. When my users intend to perform a single sign out from my application, the IDP does not recognize the user.
How could I send the user back to the IDP from my WIF ASP.NET application for refreshing the IDP session?